# Choosing initial approximation and the function in Fixed point iteration method

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

In Numerical analysis, to solve an equation of the form $f(x)=0$ in $[a,b]$, fixed point iteration method is useful.

To this end, we can write $f(x)=0$ in the form $g(x)=x$ and try to find a fixed point of $g$.

But there are many ways to find such function $g$. I am confused which $g$ should one choose? For example, in Burden and Faires book, it is assumed that if $|g'(x)|\leq k<1$ for every $x\in(a,b)$, then for any initial guess $x_0$ the sequence $x_n=g(x_{n-1})$ will converge to the fixed point of $g$. But it seems problematic to prove that $|g'(x)|\leq k<1$ for every $k\in(a,b)$.

My question is there an alternative way to find a suitable $g$ to ensure the convergence of the fixed point iteration method? In particular, can we choose $g$ and $x_0$ the initial guess so that only the condition $|g'(x_0)|<1$ will ensure the convergence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the condition you mention (contractivity) does not ensure the convergence for all $x_0 \in [a,b]$, it only ensures convergence if $x_0$ is close enough to the fixed point. If you want to ensure convergence for all initial approximations, you should also require invariance, i.e. $g([a,b]) \subseteq [a,b]$. So, regarding your questions,

1. I don't really understand why you are concerned about showing that $|g'(x)|\leq k <1$. Sure, this can be hard do do analytically if $g$ is "complicated", but is not a real obstacle.
2. The condition $|g'(x_0)|<1$ assures nothing. Local convergence would be a consequence of $|g'(z)|<1$, where $z$ is the fixed point.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that $g:[a,b]\to [a,b]$. So for the convergence, $|g'(x)|\leq k<1$ we need to check for every $x\in(a,b)$ is the only condition?  I am concerned because if I want to use this method to solve some problem, then first I need to choose a suitable $g$.

Comment: @Math This is a sufficient condition, not a necessary one. So, the method can converge even if contractivity condition is not satisfied. As long as $g$ is continuous, if $x_n$ converges, the limit is a fixed point of $g$. So, if you have numerical evidence that $x_n$ is converging to some point, you are actually approaching the  correct solution.

Comment: Look up the Banach fixed-point theorem and the Newton-Kantorovich theorem for proofs of the convergence of general fixed-point methods and the conditions required.